# Get current year, day and month in delphi

Tags: delphi, validation, datetime

I basically want this C# code:

```cs
if (month > currentDate.Month || (day > currentDate.Day && month > currentDate.Month)) 
{
    age = currentDate.Year - year - 1;
}
else
{
    age = currentDate.Year - year;
}
```

Into to delphi. But the problem I have is that I don't know how to get the current year, month and day as integers so I can do some calculations. I've click on every result on google that relates to this but none of them have helped me.
(Really not a fan of delphi, but its the language we're doing in my computing class)

Comment: Looking at the functions here would be a good start http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/ByFunction.asp?Main=DatesAndTimes

Comment: Take a look at  [DecodeDate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/de/System.SysUtils.DecodeDate) and [Now](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_Now.html)

Comment: For ex. `if Month > MonthOf(Now) or ((Day > DayOf(Now)) and (Month > MonthOf(Now)) then Age := YearOf(Now) - Year - 1 else Age := YearOf(Now) - Year;`, but there's a lot to improve on such code.

Comment: When using YearOf I get undeclared identifier, do I need add something in the 'uses' thing?. (Where system.sysutils is)

Comment: MonthOf, YearOf and many other Date and Time related functions can be found in DateUtils

Comment: DateUtils is what you need. Did you search in the documentation, or is it just easier to ask here?

Comment: Dan: Add System.DateUtils to your uses clause.

Comment: Got it guys thanks :). @David I actually did try adding DateUtils in the uses but I got an error so I then wasn't sure. Although now you guys said it does need to be I saw that there is a uses folder so I realized I need to add it via that folder structure thing.

Comment: What folder structure thing? You just add `DateUtils` to the uses. You will make very little headway programming if you ignore the messages contained in errors. Don't ever say "I got an error". Report precisely what the error was. Don't just guess and try random things out. Understand what is wrong and fix it properly.

Comment: Wondering if it an SO glitch that the C# code is partially shown as a comment...

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers No, it's formatted as it it were Delphi. And it would be a comment in Delphi wouldn't it? Look at my upcoming edit to the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wondered (and still do) if the SO code highlighter would only take the code itself, or use more context to estimate the programming language. In these simple code examples, I'd probably get rid of the braces.

Comment: @Jeroen It uses the tags to infer language.

Comment: And to think I thought it was great when I learned that the highschool students of South Africa would be learning Delphi.  We have years of this kind of lazy question to look forward to.

Answer (score 9):

A literal translation would be as follows:

```
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

if (month > MonthOf(Date)) or ((day > DayOf(Date)) and (month > MonthOf(Date)) then 
begin
  age := YearOf(Date) - year - 1;
end else
begin
  age := YearOf(Date) - year;
end;
```

But that is the not the best translation.  If nothing else, the repeated calls to `Date()` cause a problem if the code is running at midnight when the current date changes.  The following would be safer:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  wYear, wMonth, wDay: Word:
begin
  ...
  DecodeDate(Date, wYear, wMonth, wDay);
  if (month > wMonth) or ((day > wDay) and (month > wMonth) then 
  begin
    age := wYear - year - 1;
  end else
  begin
    age := wYear - year;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, have a look at the `DateUtils.YearsBetween()` function:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils, DateUtils;

age := YearsBetween(Date, EncodeDate(year, month, day));
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `DateUtils` to your uses, then you can use `DayOf` for the day of the month, `MonthOf` for the of the year and `YearOf` for the year part. `Date` gives you the current date to pass into these functions.

Comment: Or use `SysUtils.DecodeDate()`, which returns the month, day, and year in a single function call. `DayOf()`, `MonthOf()`, and `YearOf()` use `DecodeDate()` internally, so you would be calling `DecodeDate()` three times and discarding 2/3 of the returned data.

Comment: I like your answer better, so have a +1. Especially since I didn't keep in mind the repeated calls to date around midnight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DecodeDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.DecodeDate) to separate out the year, month, and day values from the return value of the [`Date`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Date) function in a single function call:

```
var
  CurrYear, CurrMonth, CurrDay: Word;
begin
  DecodeDate(Date(), CurrYear, CurrMonth, CurrDay);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Scratch the "older versions". DateUtils been there for more than 10 years.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: We get questions here about Delphi 3, 5, and 7 frequently. If someone using one of those finds this in a search, it's still useful. :-) I don't use anything earlier than D2007 myself.

Comment: `DecodeDate()` still exists in modern versions, and works just as well as it always has. Just because the `DateUtils` unit exists does not always make it the best choice to use for every situation. If you need all three date values - day, month, year - it makes sense to call `DecodeDate()`, which returns all three values in a single call, instead of using `DateUtils` functions that separate the date values into multiple function calls.